# How to do isolated storage in Wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to store  data in dropdown list and between 2 radio button I have to store one value using isolated storage in Window phone 7 a 
How to do isolated storage in Wp7?

Comment: Have you read the various tutorials and pages about Isolated Storage? Your question is too vague at the moment.

Comment: I just wrote a free isolated storage dll. Very easy to use http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47

Answer (score 6):

The **easiest** way to do it, is to use the [IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class/property - it is a great dumpbin for all your small temporary data that must survive whatever happens. Generally, that object is automatically saved/restored from the ISO store, but be careful in believing that - it works if your app is closed gracefully. If you want to guard that against for example, an application crash/etc - you still should periodically manually call SAVE on this object.

Some links/tuts:
MSDN: quite nice explanation an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx
first-whetever from google http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings

Answer (score 5):

This is the code snippet I use for loading and saving High scores in a WP7 app, tweak it to suit your needs. It could save millions of lives :D

```
private void LoadHighScore()
    {
        // open isolated storage, and load data from the savefile if it exists.
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
        using (IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
#else
        using (IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain())
#endif
        {
            if (savegameStorage.FileExists("guessthecard.txt"))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = savegameStorage.OpenFile("guessthecard.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    if (fs != null)
                    {
                        // Reload the saved high-score data.
                        byte[] saveBytes = new byte[4];
                        int count = fs.Read(saveBytes, 0, 4);
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            highScore = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(saveBytes, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save highscore

    public async void UnloadContent()
    {
        //  SAVE HIGHSCORE
        // Save the game state (in this case, the high score).
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
        IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
#else
        IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain();
#endif

        // open isolated storage, and write the savefile.
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
        using (fs = savegameStorage.CreateFile("guessthecard.txt"))
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                // just overwrite the existing info for this example.
                byte[] bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(highScore);
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            CardGuess item = new CardGuess { Text = highScore.ToString() };
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<CardGuess>().InsertAsync(item);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as in normal Silverlight (except for the non existing site storage). See any tutorials/books for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class for Isolated storage
 public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        /// 
        /// method to get value of given key
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static T GetKeyValue(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key))
                    return (T)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key];
                else
                    return default(T);
            }
            catch (Exception) { return default(T); }
        }
        /// 
        /// method to set value of key
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static void SetKeyValue(string key, T value)
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key))
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key] = value;
            else
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add(key, value);

```
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// method to remove key from isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public static void RemoveKey(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove(key);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// method to check when a key exists in isolated storage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool HasKey(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(key))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception) { return false; }
    }

}
```

then store data as
ApplicationSettings.SetKeyValue("key", value);
retrieve
var aaa=ApplicationSettings.GetKeyValue("key");