# Save IEnumerable in Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I used the isolated storage before to save text files, xml files and images. However, is it possible to save variables of type **IEnumerable** using **IsolatedStorage** or any other resource in windows phone 7??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding core concepts.. There is no such thing as "saving variables", you save objects. Your variable points to an object, and that objects implements IEnumerable. Is On WP7, it is the object's **actual** class that determines whether that object can be serialized and stored on the ISO directly. If that actual collection class does not support serialization, you will have to re-wrap all its current elements into a List/Array/Dictionary/Stack/Queue - literally whatever what supports being serialized - and store that instead of.

Once you have an serializable collection, then your code for saving gets reduced to something as trivial as:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["blah"] = your_serializable_collection;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

and in general, that's it. Retrieving is similar:

```
var items = (SomeCollection)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["blah"];
```

where SomeCollection may be an IEnumerable, a List/Array/Dictionary/Stack/Queue - whatever you had put there and whatever is implemented by the actual collection class.

If you want, you may use IsolatedStorageFile and write files directly, but unless you have a good reason to - there's no point in it, as using the common dictionary is far simplier.

In my other post you'll find some links:
[How to do isolated storage in Wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344001/how-to-do-isolated-storage-in-wp7/7354581#7354581)

Answer (score 1):

Use for saving/loading of data List which are serializable out of the box. Last time i tried deserialize an IEnumerable I got errors...

Comment: Ok this is easy because we can easily switch between list and IEnumerable.  
Can you provide the code to save and load a list because i searched online and found nothing.

Comment: Use a serializer of your chose, like [written here](http://j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2011/02/10/Simple-Data-Serialization-on-WP7.aspx).